# Apache 2.2 CGI perl timeouts, still times out even with periodic prints

Tags: ajax, perl, apache, timeout, cgi

I have a cgi code that is being called by AJAX from clientside javascript. However, the result of the call is discarded by the client.

On the backend this code occurs:

```
$|=1;
my $i = 0;
while (<$fh_echo>)
{
    #To prevent apache timing out the cgi script. 
    print "." if $i % 100 == 0;

    #Do stuff
    $i++;
}
```

Despite the periodic print out, this still times out:

```
[warn] [client 10.23.12.87] Timeout waiting for output from CGI script 
[error] [client 10.23.12.87] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: ap_content_length_filter: apr_bucket_read() failed
```

I figure the fact that javascript discards the output shouldn't have any form of impact on whether or not apache allows the cgi script to continue. If so, then what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the timeout for CGI scripts is asking for trouble. Given that the result of the call is discarded by the client, you should instead `fork`, have the child complete the work and the parent finish quickly.

See [Watching long processes through CGI](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/LinuxMag/col39.html) for an explanation. Specifically,

> And now the fun part. We're going to fork starting in line 31. This permits the parent process to tell Apache that we're done responding to this request, while letting the child go off to perform the long traceroute. …
>
> The child goes on, but it must first close STDOUT, because otherwise Apache will think there might still be some output coming for the browser, and won't respond to the browser or release the connection until this is all resolved.

Comment: And, are you closing `STDOUT` in the child and exiting immediately in the parent?

Comment: Oh! closing STDOUT seems to make it work now. I'll do some more testing, but so far I have yet to get any time out errors.

Answer (score 1):

Perl buffers output, please make sure `$|` is set to a non-zero value.

Apache will timeout the request unless you disable that [functionality](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#timeout), whether there is something returned or not from the cgi side.

Comment: Crap I totally forgot! Thanks, I'll see if this helps. I usually just put newline after my prints so it flushes the output.

Comment: Just saw that $| was set to 1 in the beginning of my code. So that means the whole time buffer WAS turned off, and this is still occurring. So it must be something else hm.

Comment: Is the apache side timeout turned off aswell?

Comment: Shouldn't it still allow the cgi to continue despite apache configurations? I thought the timeouts are only for if the script prints out nothing.

Comment: As far as I know the timeout applies regardless whether there is something returned or not, what should matter is the script finishing execution and if not, the request is timed out.

Please take a look at the TimeOut httpd.conf setting.

Comment: Timeout 120, so should I just put in a huge number?

Timeout 987987987987? Or is there a hardcoded value (0 perhaps) that means infinite? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout Doesnt seem to specify.

Comment: I'd try TimeOut 0 first to disable it.

Comment: Timeout 0 causes apache to timeout scripts immediately, I guess I'll just have to put in an arbitrary large number then.